# Who was killed in the Sept of Baelor?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Who exactly were killed in the Sept of Baelor?

Is there a list of all the Lords and ladies etc.

Comment: 9, because 7 8 9 :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are asking specifically about Lords and Ladies, Among the noted nobles, following are among the casualties:

1. Ser Kevan Lannister
2. Lord Mace Tyrell
3. Brother Loras (Formerly Ser Loras Tyrell)
4. Queen Margaery Tyrell
5. Brother Lancel (Formerly Ser Lancel Lannister, Killed in the foundations below the Sept)

A List of such nobles (Similar to this one) is at [GoT Wikia](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Destruction_of_the_Great_Sept_of_Baelor), already compiled.

However there is no such list available for other attendants as they were just cast as extras and weren't major characters. You can see the [Cast credits at imDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4283094/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) but there are no credits there for any Lord or lady present at the Sept other than the ones we already know.

Comment: Lords, ladies "etc." -- The High Sparrow is a pretty big one to stick under the "etc." heading.

Comment: Technically, Lancel bought it UNDER the Sept....   :D

Comment: @New_DM_Tryingtobesneaky High Sparrow is not a noble aristocrat. Lord and Ladies are titles reserved for the Aristocracy. He does not fit there.

Comment: Although not killed in the Sept, Tommen committed suicide because of it, could be worth an honourable mention.